# Update a column with the max trackingNumber and increment by 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that I am building in SQL Server that is looking for the max tracking Number and adding 1 to the current value for each record with the same lotno in the job where tracking number is zero. The query that I have is updating all the records in this job with the same number. I need each record in this job to have a different number.

Here is the query I have:

```
UPDATE TEST.DBO.J_CordToolARCCutSheetPlanning 
SET TrackingNumber = (SELECT (MAX(trackingNumber) + 1) AS track 
                      FROM TEST.DBO.J_CordToolARCCutSheetPlanning j)
WHERE JobNumber = '1234'
```

Sample:

```
Job   LotNO        SerialNo TrackingNumber
------------------------------------------
1234  199111 -001  40001    0
1234  199111 -001  40033    0
1234  199111 -004  40050    0
1234  199111 -004  40051    0
1234  199111 -008  40111    5
1234  199111 -008  40112    5
```

In this example the max tracking Number is 5.

I need it to update each record by the max (5) plus one.

This is what I need it to do

```
Job   LotNO        SerialNo TrackingNumber
------------------------------------------
1234  199111 -001  40001    6
1234  199111 -001  40033    6
1234  199111 -004  40050    7
1234  199111 -004  40051    7
1234  199111 -008  40111    5
1234  199111 -008  40112    5
```

Comment: But your example data *isn't* updating every row by 1? You are reusing the same tracking number for the same lot number?

Comment: If the job and lotNo is the same update update the tracking number with the max number (which is 5 in the example plus 1.

Comment: Then please update your question to clarify that, because currently you say " I need each record in this job to have a different number."

Answer (score 2):

You can use an updatable CTE to accomplish a unique row number as follows below using [`dense_rank`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to generate your required values.

Note: as it stands your description is inconsistent with your desired results. Your description says a unique row number whereas your desired results show a common tracking number per lot number.

Also you would be much better off using an automatic sequence (identity column or sequence) rather than manually calculating this.

```
with cte as (
    -- Choose a suitable ordering column
    select
        -- Sample data assigns the same number for the entire lot
        dense_rank() over (order by LotNo) rn
        -- If a unique number per row is required (as written) use row_number
        --row_number() over (order by LotNo, SerialNo) rn
    from dbo.J_CordToolARCCutSheetPlanning
    where JobNumber = '1234'
    and TrackingNumber = 0
)
update cte set TrackingNumber = dr + (select max(trackingNumber) + 1 from dbo.J_CordToolARCCutSheetPlanning);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `DENSE_RANK` window function to rank the row in `LotNO` and add the result with max `trackingNumber`

```
UPDATE
    J_CordToolARCCutSheetPlanning 
SET
    J_CordToolARCCutSheetPlanning.TrackingNumber = CASE WHEN t.trackingNumber != t.max_trackingNumber THEN t.max_trackingNumber + t.seq ELSE t.trackingNumber END
FROM
  (SELECT *,
       DENSE_RANK() over(ORDER BY t.LotNO) AS seq,
       (SELECT MAX(trackingNumber) FROM J_CordToolARCCutSheetPlanning) AS max_trackingNumber
  FROM J_CordToolARCCutSheetPlanning t
  WHERE JobNumber = '1234') t
WHERE J_CordToolARCCutSheetPlanning.SerialNo = t.SerialNo
```

*demo in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=97ea2a3a7d7231edc7cca63a796772e5)*